# Installing Windows 7 after installing Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 14.10

I had little knowledge of Ubuntu before I installed it, and I still have little knowledge of it with it installed. I'm trying to work my way around Ubuntu 14.10 and I'm in utter confusion. Nothing makes sense, because I'm used to the extremely simple nature of Windows.

I made the decision to wipe Windows from my computer entirely and replace it with Ubuntu. I'm stuck with an operating system that's too intricate for me to understand and I'm not really sure how to get Windows back. I'd like to replace Ubuntu with Windows (like it used to be) but I'm not sure how to. I know nothing about the terminal, nothing about partitions, just nothing. I've tried to go through a few of the topics on here with the same problem but I didn't really understand how to go about any of it.

Hey, I might just buy a different computer sooner or later. But for now, I need Windows back on this computer.

Comment: We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and the people here are very good at dual-booting and removing Windows, but not very good at getting it back once it was removed...  However, on http://superuser.com, a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at deleting Ubuntu and installing Windows, so you might be better off there.  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

Just boot into the Windows disk, select the drive you wish to overwrite, and go through the normal Windows installation. It should wipe it clean and install Windows on it.

Although, in Ubuntu, it's become so simple to use that you rarely should need to mess with your disk partitions or open up a terminal, and in most cases you can get support on using the command-line here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get an installation media of windows. Because when you installed Ubuntu it deleted the windows partitions and installed itself. As such you need find or buy Windows again. in the form of a USB stick or a CD of windows. After that its a simple steps to follow the windows install steps.

Answer (score 0):

If windows is so extremely simple compared to linux, why did you manage to install linux, but cannot install windows?

When you installed ubuntu, did you choose replace windows or did you choose a side by side installation?

Which version of windows and ubuntu are you using?

Legacy bios or uefi boot?

Do you have a windows install or recovery media?

And last but not least, whhat are your usability problems in ubuntu?